# filter list - C++

Tags: c++, list, filter, iterator

I would like to filter a list in C++. For that I was provided with an external function f, that compares elements. Based on that comparison, I decide which elements to keep.

**It seems like my implementation is wrong, could you help me find the error?**

Example for f:

```
bool function f(a, b){
if (a + b % 3 != 0){
    return true; // keep element
}
return false; }
```

I would like to emphasis that this is just an example for the sake of keeping this simple.

My implementation **should** work like this (elements separated by ___):

```
1____2____3____4____5____6____7____8
^    ^
f(1, 2) == false. Discard 2. 

1____3____4____5____6____7____8
^    ^
now compare the next element with 1 
f(1, 3) == true. Keep 3. Move first pointer to 3

1____3____4____5____6____7____8
     ^    ^
Compare 3 with 4 ...

1____3____4____5____6____7____8
          ^    ^
remove 5, since f(4, 5) == false

1____3____4____6____7____8
          ^    ^
keep 6, move pointer 

1____3____4____6____7____8
               ^    ^
1____3____4____6____7____8
                    ^    ^
remove 8. 

1____3____4____6____7
                    ^
Nothing more to compare. Terminate.
```

I implement the "removing", by moving valid elements to another list and moving the iterator to the next element in the original list, but actually removing them would be ok, too.

```
list<node> result;
list<node>::iterator i = path.begin();
element firstElement = *i;
result.push_back(firstElement);
for (; i != path.end();)
{
    if (++i == path.end())
    {
        break;
    }
    // compare with next node
    int d = distance(firstElement.id, (*i).id);
    if (d <= (*i).valFrom)
    {
        // add edge to result
        result.push_back(*i);
        firstElement = *i;
    }
}
```

**working example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int f(int a, int b)
{
    if (a + b % 3 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{

    list<int> path = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    list<int> result;
    bool skip = false;
    list<int>::iterator i = path.begin();
    int firstint = *i;
    result.push_back(firstint);
    for (; i != path.end();)
    {
        if (++i == path.end())
        {
            break;
        }
        // compare with next int
        if (f(firstint, *i))
        {
            // add edge to result
            result.push_back(*i);
            firstint = *i;
        }
    }

    // output path
    for (list<int>::iterator i = result.begin(); i != result.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good case for using a debugger, executing step by step.

Comment: This is also a good case for using unit testing. Anyhow, I'm not sure if you are already doing that, but filtering something like that in-place is often more cumbersome than copying or even moving to a second list. In any case, please write yourself a step-by-step definition of the algorithm you want to implement, in plain prose. It helps as intermediate step to translating that to C++ lateron.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , which is why i am not doing it in place, but compying it to result

Comment: The function f is wrong, so if you are using something like it, it will fail.  However you have not shown us what you are using, so who knows?

Comment: f is provided from a libary. You can assume that it is correct, because it was tested thoroughly. I did not want to overcomplicate this post, which is why I made up a new f

Comment: The question is not complete.  What is valFrom?  And how is that initialized?  You appear to be using c++ distance function to determine distance between iterator elements, and then comparing that to some random value valFrom, I have no idea why you would compare one to the other.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @SeanF Sorry for that. ValFrom ist a property of the objects in the list. It is not important for the actual question, though.

Comment: @n.m. I included a working example. It does what it should, but apparently not always

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "does what it should, but apparently not always". `f` always returns `true` for all of your list, so nothing is ever removed. There is no wiggle room, always is always and never is never. [mcve] ought to include expected/desired output and actual output, so please add those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you want something like:

```
std::list<int> mylist{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

mylist.remove_if([](auto val)
{
    return ((val % 2) == 1);
});
```

this removes all uneven values from the list

if you want the results in another list:

```
std::list<int> mylist{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
std::list<int> mylistFilered;

std::copy_if(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), std::back_inserter(mylistFilered),[](auto val)
{
    return ((val % 2) == 1);
});
```

for filter based on 2 consequitive elements, we need a little helper list. for example like this:

```
std::list<int> mylist{ 1,2,3,5,7,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
std::list<int> keepElement;
std::list<int> mylistFilered;

std::transform(mylist.begin(), --mylist.end(), ++mylist.begin(), std::back_inserter(keepElement),[](auto a, auto b)
{
    return ((a + b) % 3 != 0);
});
```

or, if you e.g. have can use -1 as a invalid value like this:

```
std::list<int> mylist{ 1,2,3,5,7,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
std::list<int> mylistFilered;

std::transform(mylist.begin(), --mylist.end(), ++mylist.begin(), std::back_inserter(mylistFilered),[](auto a, auto b)
{
    if ((a + b) % 3 != 0)
        return a;
    else
        return -1;
});

mylistFilered.remove_if([](auto val)
{
    return (val == -1);
});
```

Comment: I would have to change that a little bit to something like this... 

How can I do that? 

  std::copy_if(path.begin(), path.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [](auto val) {
        return (distance(firstElement, SecondElement));
    });

Comment: Since I am not concerned about the "eveness" of a particular element, but the "eveness" of the combination of two elements

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem. If you try this solution (with input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), it will output a list with the elements 2, 3, 5, 6. The correct solution would be a list with the elements 1, 3, 4, 6